# Pear installed, but includes not working

Tags: php, wamp, pear

I have finally got Pear running through the Pear2 system, but my path seems to be screwed up, I guess. I am trying to include HTML_Tables for a tutorial I am doing, and it shows that it's not there. 
I originally tried to setup pear in the php bin, (it's still there), but then through the Pear2 I set it up in wamp/www/pear. It installed and shows up in the command line, but using it to include packages, it appears the path is off.

```
Failed opening required 'HTML/Table.php' (include_path='.;c:\php\includes:c:\wamp\Zend;.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR') in C:\wamp\www\php-site-training\cars_table.php on line 5
```

--oh, I meant to mention that I manually updated the path, to show the wamp settings, but the error still shows the phpbin, as shown above.

Comment: What's the code you're using to include HTML_Table.php?

Comment: How important is it to use pear anyway? I am still growing as a php developer, and don't want to waste too much time on something I won't need.

Comment: it actually says PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR is not set correctly. fix with env variable or modify default in pear.bat.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a random guess, try `require 'PEAR/HTML/Table.php';`  I'm kind of confused as to what the actual error you're seeing is, and I'm not entirely sure of what you're php configuration is, or where you actually have PEAR installed.

As for how important PEAR is, it depends.  It has some useful tools, but I think some of the functionality of those tools ended up in the various frameworks.  However, some of the tools and libraries in PEAR are quite useful.  In general, if a PEAR library will help you do something, it's worth setting it up, otherwise, it might not be worth it.